# jquery confirmation popup form with input values after clicking on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a form, after clicking on submit i should get a popup with entered values for confirmation with edit and submit buttons.
I see lots of examples but nothing is exact.

help is appreciated.

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#list").click(function() {
                var cun = $("#list").val();

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/prakash/popup form/view.php",
            data: {'data':cun},
            success: function(data){
                    //redirect to id using response
                    //window.location.replace("http://yoursite.com/products/" + response);
                    $('.display').html(data);
            }
    });


    }); 

        });

</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function() {
      var cun = $("#dis").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/prakash/popup form/add.php",
    data: {'data':cun},
    success: function(data){
        //redirect to id using response
        //window.location.replace("http://yoursite.com/products/" + response);
        $('.display').html(data);
    }
});


}); 

  });
</script>
<script>
$(function(){       
    // jQuery UI Dialog   

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Submit Form": function() {
                document.testconfirmjq.submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $('form#testconfirmjq').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $("p#dialog-name").html($("input#name").val());
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });
```

});

```
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
</div>

<div align="center" data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#" id="add" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">Add New</a>

    <a href="#" id="list" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">Show List</a>   
</div>

<div class="display" align="center" display="inline">
<table id="dis" border="0">
        <form id="testconfirmjq" method="POST" action="insert.php"> 
            <tr><td>Name</td><td> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td></tr> 
            <tr><td>Age</td><td><input type="text" name="age" id="datepicker-13" size="30"></td></tr> 
            <tr><td>City</td><td> <input type="text" name="city"></td></tr> 
            <tr><td><input id="button" type="submit" name="send" value="Submit"></td></tr>
        </form>
</table>
```

You entered your Name as:

If this is correct, click Submit Form.

To edit, click Cancel.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: here is my code...in this i am calling ajax for showing list of users in the same page and it will replace the form and show the list. all the buttons are working but submit in the first form is not working. i think submit is not working because i am calling php on form action and ajax on form submit.

Answer (score 0):

This code may be help you

```js
function send(){
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var r = confirm(name);
    if (r == true) {
      //apply with your function(it will be excuted)
       return true;
    } else {
      
       return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="demo.php" onsubmit="return send()">
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <input type="button" value="send">
</form>
```